# JBoss: How to ignore Press any key to continue, without editing the jboss-cli.bat?

Tags: batch-file, jboss, jboss-cli

We are trying to read the JBoss status using the `jboss-cli.bat` command.

```
jboss-cli.bat -c --command=":read-attribute(name=server-state)" > "$env:JBOSS_HOME\JbossServerStatus.txt"
```

Storing the status in the `TXT` file. Since "**Press any key to continue**" occurs, the controller doesn't return back.

Is there any way to ignore the Press any key to continue without editing the `jboss-cli.bat`? We know that by adding `set NOPAUSE = true`, will avoid this problem, but we are looking for solution without editing the file.

Comment: You don't need to change the batch file, just define the variable before calling the batch file. `set "NOPAUSE=true" & jsboss-cli.bat .... `

Comment: @MCND It is not working. Here's my code
set NOPAUSE="true"
jboss-cli.bat -c --command=":read-attribute(name=server-state)"
Am running this as .PS1 file

Comment: Try: `< nul jboss-cli.bat ....`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `jboss-cli.bat` includes a line as

```
 if "x%NOPAUSE%" == "x" pause
```

so, we only need to declare a environment variable called `NOPAUSE` and set it to some value before calling the `jboss-cli.bat`

```
set "NOPAUSE=true"
jboss-cli.bat .....
```

If the `joss-cli.bat` is being called from a powershell script (from comments), then we will need to use something like

```
$env:NOPAUSE = "true"
.\jboss-cli.bat .....
```